# Selecting ID that appears more than once, different data

Tags: sql, ms-access

Selecting from 4 columns: ID, LICENSE, CODE, ABBR

The ID can appear more than once with different data in the remaining columns. I want to exclude any records where the ID appears only once.

This is for MS Access 2016.

```
SELECT ID, LICENSE, CODE, ABBR
FROM tblLicense
WHERE CODE IN ("A", "B", "C")
GROUP BY ID, LICENSE, CODE, ABBR
HAVING COUNT(ID)>1;
```

If I run a simple select query without the count I can see records where the ID appears only once, as well as records where the ID appears more than once. But when I add the COUNT(), I get zero records. I was expecting it to exclude any records where the ID appears more than once. Not sure how to rectify this. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wrong grouping, just`Group By ID`nothing else or a all groups contain only one row if `ID, LICENSE, CODE, ABBR`is unique. and then `Count(ID) = 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a NOT IN for the id with count= 1

```
select  ID, LICENSE, CODE, ABBR 
from  
FROM tblLicense
WHERE CODE IN ("A", "B", "C") 
AND id not in  (
  select id 
  from tblLicense
  WHERE CODE IN ("A", "B", "C") 
  group by id  
  having count(*) = 1 
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm guessing I didn't get what I needed due to not using a subquery. I will file this away for future use!

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this using joins, e.g.:

```
select t1.id, t1.license, t1.code, t1.abbr
from tbllicense t1 inner join
(
    select t2.id
    from tbllicense t2
    where t2.code in ("A", "B", "C")
    group by t2.id
    having count(*) > 1
) q on t1.id = q.id
where t1.code in ("A", "B", "C")
```